# OpenVPN Server 2.3.1, how to switch from dh1024.pem to dh4096.pem

Tags: vpn, openvpn, ssl-certificate, netgear-router

I had to generate new keys to use the latest version of OpenVPN client to connect to my Netgear R7000 router, as the stock ones used MD5 which is no longer supported.

I followed a guide to generate the new keys, producing a `dh4096.pem` cert, but since the router originally used a `dh1024.pem` cert, the guide simply instructs to rename `dh4096.pem` to `dh1024.pem` and overwrite the original file.

- This works, but for both learning and OCD purposes, I would like to modify the server configuration to point to the new file keeping its real name `dh4096.pem`

  - I searched every file in the server's filesystem for `1024` in `.conf` files, `.sh` files, and everything readable containing `vpn` in its path, but with no luck.

I suspect that the OpenVPN executable looks for `dh1024.pem` by default and it's up to me to explicitly add a parameter indicating the new location or in this case the new name.

Where should I look?

```
BusyBox v1.7.2 (2017-06-15 22:36:14 CST) built-in shell (ash)
    
# /usr/local/sbin/openvpn --version
OpenVPN 2.3.1 arm-unknown-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [eurephia] [MH] [IPv6] built on Jun 15 2017
```

Comment: Don't use a `dh4096.pem` cert, as a 2048 cert is more than sufficient, just as an encryption cipher over AES128 isn't needed, serving only to slow throughput with no additional gains in security _(AES128 will remain uncrackable until >2030)_. Usually, OpenVPN config files are contained within `/etc/openvpn`. _(Just an FYI, you may want to consider flashing [OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/toh/netgear/r7000), an opensource router firmware, as your router is not only running 3yr old firmware, OpenVPN 2.4 introduced several improvements, including TLS EC cipher support, which is more efficient.)_

Comment: I considered switching to an open source firmware but from what I gathered reading online, the stock one performs better in terms of speed and stability. If anything, I would replace openvpn with a newer version (best case scenario: i cross-compile the 2.4 executable and everything else stays the same) but I'm still learning, that's too advanced for me right now

Comment: You cannot compile a new version of any of the software in OEM firmware, as the firmware isn't opensource. There are several opensource firmware OSes [DD-WRT, OpenWrt, Tomato, etc.], w/ OpenWrt generally being the most stable, having the most packages & documentation. It's not advised to use OEM firmware on routers more than a yr old if the OEM hasn't supplied an updated image (OEMs consider routers EoL after 1 - 2yrs) and opensource firmware exists due to the hundreds of security patches the OEM firmware now lacks. For stability, see the [OpenWrt Forum](http://forum.openwrt.org/)

Comment: this will be a very interesting project for the future but it does not answer my question: how do I instruct OpenVPN 2.3.1 to use dh2048.pem or dh4096.pem instead of dh1024.pem ?

Comment: By modifying the `dh` line within OpenVPN's config file [`openvpn.conf`] ([man page](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage)), which is usually contained within `/etc/openvpn` [above], however Netgear could have implemented the config in a variety of ways, including from a script that writes it to `/tmp` or `/var`, and if this is the case, you'll need to remodify it after every reboot. [Example](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/tree/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenVPN) tuned server and client configs

Comment: I updated the router's firmware to last July's version, which fixes security issues found in 2020 https://kb.netgear.com/000062112/R7000-Firmware-Version-1-0-11-106 .

I checked OpenWRT and it does not support wi-fi due to closed source drivers of the wi-fi chip. Which is pretty pointless for a wireless router, therefore I'm not switching.

Comment: Ah, I didn't read the device wiki when posting the link. Not all drivers are made available in an opensource format, which is why I always recommend to folks that when buying a router to buy one that has opensource support; OEMs, if they release any firmware updates at all, will stop supporting a router within 1 - 2yrs, considering it EoL [End of Life]. There was a developer for [DD-WRT](https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Netgear_R7000) that had previously created custom builds for Netgear devices _(Kong I think, or something similar)_, something you may want to look into in a year or so.

Comment: Well the security issues are taken care of, for now. Sadly, the new firmware does not support previous telnet enabling techniques therefore I'm fighting against the serial debug port to gain usable console access. I might open another question for that, it doesn't seem to be any readily available tool as of today, yet.

Comment: `telnet` is not secure and exploitable _(`telnet` sends all data, including passphrases, in plain text and does not support encryption)_ and it should never be enabled on a router... SSH is what should be used, however most router manufacturers do not provide SSH on their routers _(another reason opensource firmware is usually superior)_

Comment: I know, but the port 23 would close anyway after a reboot. And my router is not exposed to the internet, it's behind another modem/router from the ISP. Which is probably full of holes more than swiss cheese, but it's unlikely someone's already behind two routers and ready to sniff my telnet session